# Add another condition to Show/Hide Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow script on a form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#bizloctype').on('change',function() {
        $('#packages div').show().not(".package-" + this.value).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Basically, depending on the value of the select box `#bizloctype` (value="1","2","3" or "4") the corresponding div shows and the rest are hidden (div class="package-1","package-2","package-3", or "package-4"). Works perfectly.

BUT, I need to add an additional condition. I need the text box `#annualsales` to be another condition determining which div shows (if the value is less than 35000 then it should show package-1 only, and no other packages.

I think the below script works fine when independent of the other script but I need to find out how to marry them.

```
<script>
    $("#annualsales").change(function(){
        $(".package-1,.package-2,.package-3,.package-4").hide();
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        if(myValue  <= 35000){
           $(".package-1").show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $(".package-2").show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Help please?

Comment: which gets precedence?

Comment: @Fallenreaper. I hadn't thought about it, but I suppose the `#annualsales` should be the primary qualifier, then the `#bizloctype` would be secondary to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the logic from the anonymous functions and do something like this:

```
// handle display
function displayPackage( fieldID ) {
    var packageType = getPackageType(fieldID);
    $('#packages div').show().not(".package-" + packageType).hide();
}

// getting the correct value (1,2,3 or 4)
function getPackageType( fieldID ) {
    // default displayed type
    var v = 1;
    switch(fieldID) {
        case 'bizloctype':
            // first check it annualsales is 1
            v = (getPackageType('annualsales') == 1) ? 
              1 :  $('#' + fieldID).val();
            break;
        case 'annualsales':
            v = (parseInt($('#' + fieldID).val(),10) <= 35000) ? 1 : 2;
            break;
    }       
    return v;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#bizloctype,#annualsales').on('change',function() {
       displayPackage($(this).attr('id'));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This only works for some combinations, not all of them. If the value of `#bizloctype` is 2 and the value of `#annualsales` is greater than 36000, it doesn't show any packages at all (they are all hidden), but it should show package-2.

Comment: Which condition is missing?

Comment: If the value of `#bizloctype` is 2 and the value of `#annualsales` is greater than 36000, it doesn't show any packages at all (they are all hidden), but it should show package-2.

Comment: Sorry, code had a missing bracket, corrected that, seems to work for me, http://jsfiddle.net/uu48cu7u/ but it feels strange, because you change one item, but it has no effect since #annualsales setting is winning.

Comment: Got this to work! Thanks so much for your help! Package 3 and 4 really are just duplicates of 2, but I created them to work with my original script since it pulled the value from the field for run the function. Now that this tells it to either be 1 or 2 based on the criteria, I've just deleted 2 and 3 entirely. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, try this code out. It first adds an onChange listener to `#annualsales` which is the code you originally had. Then, for the onChange listener for `#bizloctype`, it simply checks the value of `#annualsales` before displaying the other packages.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Check value of #annualsales on change
    $("#annualsales").change(function(){
        $(".package-1,.package-2,.package-3,.package-4").hide();
        var myValue = $(this).val();
        if(myValue  <= 35000){
           $(".package-1").show();
        }

    // Only show other packages if value is > 35000
    $('#bizloctype').on('change',function() {
        $(".package-1,.package-2,.package-3,.package-4").hide();
        if ($('#annualsales').val() <= 35000) {
            $(".package-1").show();
        } else {
            $('#packages div').show().not(".package-" + this.value).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This looked promising, but if the value of `#bizloctype` is 1 and the value of `#annualsales` is less than 35000, it doesn't show any packages at all (they are all hidden), but it should show package-1 by default because option 1 was selected. If i don't enter a value in for `#annualsales`, then package-1 does display. Thoughts?

Comment: Why not just show package 1 initially before anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use JQuery you can use the `data()` function to create a simple but dynamic condition system. For example, you could annotate each element with the required conditions and then attach `change` listeners to other elements to make the condition active or inactive for the elements.

For example, with this HTML:

```
<div id="conditions">
    Condition 1: <input type="checkbox" id="check1" /> &lt;= check this<br/>
    Condition 2: <input type="checkbox" id="check2" /><br/>
    Condition 3: <input type="text" id="value1" /> &lt;= introduce 1001 or greater<br/>
    Condition 4: <input type="text" id="value2" /><br/>
</div>

<p id="thing" data-show-conditions="check1 value1-gt-1000" 
   style="display: none;">
    The thing to show.
</p>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function setShowCondition(el, condition, active) {
    var conditions = $(el).data('conditions') || {};
    conditions[condition] = active;
    $(el).data('conditions', conditions);

    var required = ($(el).data('show-conditions') || "").split(" ");
    var visible = required.every(function (c) {
        return conditions[c];
    });

    if (visible) {
        $(el).show();
    } else {
        $(el).hide();
    }
}

$("#conditions input[type='checkbox'").change(function () {
    setShowCondition('#thing',
                     $(this).attr('id'),
                     $(this).is(':checked'));
});

$("#value1").change(function () {
    var number = parseInt($(this).val());
    setShowCondition('#thing', 'value1-gt-1000', number > 1000);
});
```

You can maintain conditions easily without having to nest and combine several `if` statements.

I've prepared a sample to show this in https://jsfiddle.net/2L5brd80/.

Comment: Please add your JSFiddle code to your answers. If JSFiddle disappears from the internet, your answer becomes useless.